# Images and document not visible after migration to liferay 6.1.0 GA1

Tags: liferay-6

I upgrade from liferay 5.2.3 to 6.0.6 , it was successfully done without any error left; but when I upgrade from 6.0.6 to 6.1.0 GA1, unable to see the images and documents.
Steps related to images and documents I have done during migration(only related to documents are described).

during migration to 6.0.6 I wrote following lines to my portal-ext.prropeties file

```
image.hook.impl=com.liferay.portal.image.FileSystemHook
image.hook.file.system.root.dir=${liferay.home}/data/images
dl.hook.impl=com.liferay.documentlibrary.util.FileSystemHook
dl.hook.file.system.root.dir=${liferay.home}/data/document_library
```

I know in liferay 5.2.3 we have saved the images and documents to file system.
after this I start the server and migrated legacy permission to 6.  It was successful , I was able to see the documents and images.

Now it turn to migrate from 6.0.6 to 6.1.0 GA1 , for that I wrote in these lines

```
image.hook.impl=com.liferay.portal.image.FileSystemHook
image.hook.file.system.root.dir=${liferay.home}/data/images
dl.hook.impl=com.liferay.documentlibrary.util.FileSystemHook
dl.hook.file.system.root.dir=${liferay.home}/data/document_library
```

start tomcat, migrate permissions to 6, after successful migration , re start the server but unable to see the documents and images. when ever trying to access the file in contents getting this error in tomcat console

```
 Current URL /c/document_library/get_file?uuid=be4eecc7-8e9a-416c-aa4d-f3cbd855d759&groupId=14 generates exception: No file versions found for fileEntryId 61901
05:50:48,093 INFO  [PortalImpl:4894] com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.NoSuchFileVersionException: No file versions found for fileEntryId 61901
com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.NoSuchFileVersionException: No file versions found for fileEntryId 61901
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLFileVersionLocalServiceImpl.getLatestFileVersion(DLFileVersionLocalServiceImpl.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
```

can any one suggest what I am missing ?

Comment: one solution I found is to add the entries of files in dlfileversion from dlfilentry. as it is fine ? is it any other solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
image.hook.impl=com.liferay.portal.image.FileSystemHook
image.hook.file.system.root.dir=${liferay.home}/data/images
dl.hook.impl=com.liferay.documentlibrary.util.FileSystemHook
dl.hook.file.system.root.dir=${liferay.home}/data/document_library
```

is for telling liferay 6.1 from where to migrate documents and images

and to tell where to migrate them to you need to use new properties (this is what you were missing)

```
dl.store.impl=com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.FileSystemStore
dl.store.file.system.root.dir=/path/to/liferay6.1/document_library
```

Upgrade process will copy images and documents to new location (dl.store.file.system.root.dir) so be sure not to have same values for `dl.hook.file.system.root.dir` and `dl.store.file.system.root.dir`

EDIT

Above is for 6.1 EE.

For CE version only images should stay in original location and documents must manualy be moved/copied to new location.

Comment: One thing more I would like to ask, I find the control panel after migration not works, I mean when I go to control panel, select the pages there were no page, but in real if I do same thing from front end I can view all the pages and I can navigate to all pages, but they are not visible in control panel, while sites are also not shown what would be the problem ?

Comment: Sorry I haven't marked it the right answer yet because I haven't tested yet. ASAP I will do it :)

Comment: Do you have any errors in logs when you go to control panel (sites, pages)?