# Liferay 6.1.2 CE not displaying images after migration to other server

Tags: liferay, jboss7.x, liferay-6

We have moved a Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.1.2 CE installation **from one server to another** "as it is", by copying the war files and all directories. Everything works fine, just **the images** (located in "document_library") are **not displayed in the browser**.

On both servers, the old one and the new one, Liferay is running on JBoss 7. **Everything including the Java version is identical (or so we believe - because apparently, it is not).** Images from the theme folder are displayed, just not from the documents folder. Databases are absolutely identical.

A similar kind of issue is found in many forums and on SE, but mostly related to upgrades from, say 6.0.6 to 6.1.0 as in [Images and document not visible after migration to liferay 6.1.0 GA1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303294/images-and-document-not-visible-after-migration-to-liferay-6-1-0-ga1).

We have tried

- setting all rights to everybody
- comparing configuration files

Unfortunately, as is easy to tell, neither the sysadmin nor us developers are Liferay experts (and it is hard to find them) - this is an inherited project. Sysadmin says this has to do with the war file, so I post this question here rather than on Serverfault, for now.

**Any hint where to look and what to try next is highly appreciated.**

Comment: One thing you can check is does old and new liferay have same company id?

Comment: I have checked the admin area and googled, but the only way to get the company id I found is from code. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Check instance Id under Server -> Portal Instance section control panel

Comment: You can export LAR from OLD liferay document & media portlet to newer one provided both LR are of same version.

Comment: Thanks. It says "Instance ID" and "Web-ID", and both are identical. I will try the LAR idea.

Comment: Unlikely, though, because we really copied Liferay installation and database 1:1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70460/discussion-between-lucky-boy-and-olaf).

Comment: I hope the "document_library" folder is in the default location "/data/" directory if not please also check if the specified location in portal-ext.properties is changed. Also if the box is Linux, please check if the user-account running JBoss has access/permission to the directory "document_library". Also are you able to download files previously uploaded in document-library portlet?

Comment: @Olaf - Do you have any errors in logs ?

Comment: @PrakashK - we will check the logs. Obvious, somehow, but I needed to request them from the sysadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your document_library folder is actually the one that is used. I'm not 100% sure with the versions, but there are some things for you to check:

- If you didn't change the document library's storage location, it'll be $liferay_home/data/document_library. Some versions define $liferay_home in portal-setup-wizard.properties (or you can do so through environment variables or in portal-ext.properties). Check this, as it might point to a directory outside of your Liferay installation directory
- Either from 6.0 to 6.1 or from 6.1 to 6.2 Liferay merged the Image Gallery into the Document Library. It might be that the migration had a problem - this would have happened during the upgrade to your version.
- If you've changed the document library's storage format (default is "FileSystemStore", it's good to use "AdvancedFileSystemStore") without migrating the data between the two, the data won't be found (while the metadata stays in the database)
- Check the document library's UI: If the metadata is there (e.g. file names) but the content is not, the binary data is the definitive issue - either the storage format or the directory's location (or both) is/are wrong.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the pointers - we will try and let you know.

Comment: You were right about the document_library path! The settings in resource.repositories.root and dl.store.file.system.root.dir had changed (automatically, for some reason), so we added the missing documents there. Thanks!